# LWC Component failed to display

Tags: lightning-web-components, onclick

Hi I am new to both coding and LWC, just trying to create a simple component that displays a table of order items in two columns. I want to display only first three items then display  a "Show More" button which when clicked should display the rest. Before adding this logic component was displaying correctly but now it says:  Error during LWC component constructor phase: [items is not defined] and also "Error during LWC component constructor phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')]"

Here are my JS and html code. Any help and hints would be highly appreciated as I am really trying to understand and learn LWC. Few comments to avoid confusion, I am using custom labels from salesforce org so its not the problem with labels, and I am using @api for items because in real the value should come from a parent component.

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import  DeliveryProductDetails from '@salesforce/label/c.DeliveryProductDetails';
import  DeliveryOrderedItems from '@salesforce/label/c.DeliveryOrderedItems';
import  DeliveryItemNumber from '@salesforce/label/c.DeliveryItemNumber';
export default class ProductInfoParent extends LightningElement {
    @api items=[{
        articleNo: "A-B2-U",
        articleImageUrl: "http://cdn.parcellab.com/img/sales-cannon/parcellab-bag.jpg",
        quantity: 1,
        sku: "A-B2-U",
        product_name: "parcelLab Tote Bag"
    },
    {
        articleNo: "A-C1-L",
        articleImageUrl: "http://cdn.parcellab.com/img/sales-cannon/parcellab-cap.jpg",
        quantity: 2,
        sku: "A-C1-L",
        product_name: "parcelLab Branded Cap"
    },
    {
        articleNo: "A-B2-T",
        articleImageUrl: "http://cdn.parcellab.com/img/sales-cannon/parcellab-bag.jpg",
        quantity: 1,
        sku: "A-B2-T",
        product_name: "parcelLab Tote Bag"
    },
    {
        articleNo: "A-C1-D",
        articleImageUrl: "http://cdn.parcellab.com/img/sales-cannon/parcellab-cap.jpg",
        quantity: 2,
        sku: "A-C1-D",
        product_name: "parcelLab Branded Cap"
    }]; 

    @api showMore = (this.items.length > 3) ? false : true;

    label = {
        DeliveryProductDetails,
        DeliveryOrderedItems,
        DeliveryItemNumber,
        //ShowMore
    }; 

    
    connectedCallback(){
        this.firstThree = showThree(this.items);
        this.showMore = showMore;
    }
    
    
    showThree(items){
        let firstThree = [];
        for(let i=0 ; i <3 ; i++  ){
            firstThree.push(items[i]);
        }
        return firstThree;
    }
    
    
    showMore(items){
        let showMoreItems = [];
        if(items.length>3){
            for(let i=3 ; i <items.length ; i++  ){
                showMoreItems.push(items[i]);
            }
            return showMoreItems;
        }
        else {
            return showMoreItems=[null];
        }
    }
    
    handleClick(){
        this.showMore = true;
        showMore(this.items);
    }
    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small slds-m-bottom_small">
      <strong>{label.DeliveryProductDetails}</strong>
  </h1>
  <div>
      <table>
          <tr class="slds-m-bottom_small">
              <th class="slds-text-heading_small" width="10px">
                  <strong>{label.DeliveryOrderedItems} </strong>
              </th>
              <th class="slds-text-heading_small" width="30px">
                  <strong>{label.DeliveryItemNumber}</strong>
              </th>
          </tr>
          <template class="slds-text-heading_small" for:each={firstThree} for:item="item">
              <tr key={item.articleNo}>
                  <td>{item.quantity} x {item.product_name}</td>
                  <td>{item.articleNo}</td>
              </tr>
          </template>
          <template if:false={showMore}>
              <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Show More" title="ShowMore" onclick={handleClick}
                  class="slds-m-right_small">
              </lightning-button>
          </template>
          <template class="slds-text-heading_small" if:true={showMore} for:each={showMoreItems} for:item="item">
              <tr key={item.articleNo}>
                  <td>{item.quantity} x {item.product_name}</td>
                  <td>{item.articleNo}</td>
              </tr>
          </template>
      </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `this` missing here:

```
firstThree.push(items);
```

and here:

```
showMore = (items.length > 3) ? false : true;
```

Having to explicitly include `this.` is troublesome if you are used to languages that don't always require it.

Do also evaluate using the [lighting-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) component for future tables. It has useful stuff built in including a "load more" mechanism, and its limitations keep you from straying too far from what SLDS ties down.

Comment: There, uhh, more, than just that which is wrong (pun intended), such as `this.showMore = true`, duplicate names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a property and a function with the name name in the same class:

```
showMore = items.length > 3 ? false : true;
```

...

```
  showMore(items) {
    let showMoreItems = [];
    if (items.length > 3) {
      for (let i = 3; i < items.length; i++) {
        showMoreItems.push(items);
      }
      return showMoreItems;
    } else {
      return showMoreItems = [null];
    }
  }
```

---

You must always refer to class elements with `this`, both for functions and properties.

```
showMore(this.items);
```

Would be:

```
this.showMore(this.items);
```

Which, coincidentally, makes some of your code nonsensical:

```
this.showMore = showMore;
```

Should be:

```
this.showMore = this.showMore;
```

Which obviously has no effect.

---

There's several inefficiencies in your code, such as using Array.prototype.push when Array.prototype.slice would serve equally well:

```
showThree(items) {
  return items.slice(0, 3) // returns first 3 items
}
```

---

Some of the rest of the code makes no apparent sense, such as:

```
  return showMoreItems = [null];
```

You're trying to return a list of one element that is a null value?

---

You have to declare a property to use it. The following is problematic:

```
this.firstThree = showThree(this.items);
```

Because firstThree isn't declared at the class level.

---

Aside from that, all of this should be handled through a [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example), unless you've got some reason why you're avoiding this. It's usually sufficient for most use cases.

---

I'll stop here for now, but suffice to say, you'll want to review what I've written so far, and the lightning-datatable documentation, then post a revised version so we can help you further.